# Why am I getting an npm missing server error on Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, npm

I just installed Node.js and Vue.js and created my first project on Vue called *test* . I am now trying to set up the server by typing on cmd:

```
npm run server
```

But I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\andri\test>npm run server
npm ERR! missing script: server

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\andri\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-02-19T09_12_53_961Z-debug.log
```

Could anyone help me understand what I am missing? I googled a bit around, but have not been able to find a solution so far. I appreciate, any help!

EDIT: This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.5.22"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "root": true,
    "env": {
      "node": true
    },
    "extends": [
      "plugin:vue/essential",
      "eslint:recommended"
    ],
    "rules": {},
    "parserOptions": {
      "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
  },
  "postcss": {
    "plugins": {
      "autoprefixer": {}
    }
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "> 1%",
    "last 2 versions",
    "not ie <= 8"
  ]
}
```

Comment: can you show your package.json file.

Comment: @MohammadRaheem I updated the question and included it

Comment: You should run: npm run serve, not server...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `npm run server` with **`npm run serve`**

## Explanation

In your `package.json` under the `scripts` key you don't have a `server` script. But you do have a `serve` one. To run a certain script with `npm run` **it needs to be in `scripts`** inside your `package.json`

Answer (score 9):

1- type the folowing first

```
vue add @vue/cli-service
```

2- add following code to package.json if there were not

"scripts": {
"serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
"build": "vue-cli-service build"
},

3- type code ==>  npm run serve  <=== for serve or type==> npm run build for build <==

```
npm run serve
```

or following to build

```
npm run build
```

if only doesnt work you just  run following and reapeat again

```
npm install

npm init
```

Answer (score 3):

First type in your terminal:

```
npm install
npm start
npm run serve
```

I solved my problem this way and it works perfectly on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the right directory that contain :

.idea

node_modules

public

src
.

.

.

and then write  npm run serve again

Just this